# Closest pair location on MongoDB in only one query

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I have a nodes database extracted from OpenStreetMap and the data is structured like this:

```js
[
{_id: 0, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}},
{_id: 1, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}, ${key}: ${value}},
{_id: 2, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}, ${key}: ${value}},
{_id: 3, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}},
{_id: 4, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}, ${key}: ${value}},
]
```

As we know, OpenStreetMap has tons of tags containing keys and values.
I'm trying to query the closest pair of nodes that contains a specific tag in only one query. I couldn't go much further than an simple aggregation function matching the nodes data base. In the example bellow I use the tag power: tower, but it is not mandatory to be that one.

```js
  const result = await client.nodes_collection
    .aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          power: 'tower',
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'nodes',
          as: 'closestNode',
          pipeline: [{ $match: { power: 'tower' } }],
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$closestNode',
      },
      {
        $match: {
          'closestNode._id': { $ne: '$_id' },
        },
      }
]).toArray()
```

P.S: It is mandatory to be in only one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

For mongoDB **version 5.3 or higher** (With the help of @Juliana Aragão):

```
db.nodes.aggregate([
  {$match: {power: "tower"}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "nodes",
      as: "closestNode",
      let: {coords: "$location.coordinates"},
      pipeline: [
        {$geoNear: {
            near: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: "$$coords"
            },
            distanceField: "distFromMe",
            spherical: true,
            query: {power: "tower"}
        }},
        {$skip: 1},
        {$limit: 1},
        {$project: {distFromMe: 1}}
      ]
  }},
  {$set: {closestNode: {$first: "$closestNode"}}},
  {$sort: {"closestNode.distFromMe": 1}},
  {$limit: 1}
])
```

For **older versions of mongoDB**, `$geoNear` does not support the `coordinates` as a parameter, thus one option is to create the calculation by ourselves. This solution includes calculating the distance between all pairs: O(n^2):

```
db.nodes.aggregate([
  {$match: {power: "tower"}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "nodes",
      as: "closestNode",
      let: {
        long: {$multiply: [{$first: "$location.coordinates"}, 0.017452778]},
        lat: {$multiply: [{$last: "$location.coordinates"}, 0.017452778]}
      },
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {power: "tower"}},
        {$set: {
            lat: {$multiply: [{$last: "$location.coordinates"}, 0.017452778]},
            long: {$multiply: [{$first: "$location.coordinates"}, 0.017452778]}
        }},
        {$set: {distFromMe: {
              $let: {
                vars: {
                  dlon: {$subtract: ["$long", "$$long"]},
                  dlat: {$subtract: ["$lat", "$$lat"]},
                  rlon: {$divide: [
                      {$multiply: [6378137, {$cos: {$avg: ["$lat", "$$lat"]}}]},
                      {$sqrt: {$subtract: [
                            1,
                            {$multiply: [
                                0.00669437,
                                {$pow: [{$sin: {$avg: ["$lat", "$$lat"]}}, 2]}
                            ]}
                      ]}}
                  ]},
                  rlat: {$divide: [
                      {$multiply: [6378137, {$subtract: [1, 0.00669437]}]},
                      {$pow: [
                          {$subtract: [
                              1,
                              {$multiply: [
                                  0.00669437,
                                  {$pow: [
                                      {$sin: {$avg: ["$lat", "$$lat"]}},
                                      2
                                  ]}
                              ]}
                          ]},
                          1.5
                      ]}
                  ]}
                },
                in: {$max: [
                    {$sqrt: [{$add: [
                            {$pow: [{$multiply: ["$$dlon", "$$rlon"]}, 2]},
                            {$pow: [{$multiply: ["$$dlat", "$$rlat"]}, 2]}
                    ]}]},
                    1
                ]}
            }}
        }},
        {$sort: {distFromMe: 1}},
        {$skip: 1},
        {$limit: 1},
        {$project: {distFromMe: 1}}
      ]
  }},
  {$set: {closestNode: {$first: "$closestNode"}}},
  {$sort: {"closestNode.distFromMe": 1}},
  {$limit: 1}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lXR6IO2TmCK).

The distance calculation is according to [this ref by @jimirwin‏](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.geo.satellite-nav/KRX55VzvzKo/lWOYir-g_AsJ):

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to query based on your solution, but using geoNear to use more mongodb native functions [here it is](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wOKoMC5GEF3). It won't work on the playground because it doesn't support 2dsphere

Comment: @Juliana Aragão, Using $geonear inside the pipeline is much better. I was not aware of the option of newer mongoDB versions to get the `coordinates` as a parameter. I updated the answer according to your suggestion, so other people will be able to see it easily.

Comment: Hey @nimrod-serok. I hope this message finds you because I can't tag your username properly. I had to amplificate the query to get the k-closest pair, and I had some Issues with that. The normal behavior is showing both results of a pair based on distance back and forth one underneath other, but somehow it is breaking it in the middle. [Here](https://pastebin.com/9Cs0HecW) I wrote what I got and the data to reproduce the issue. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I don't see any problem. The code is working as expected, as you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qTCK6DNSnJE), with all the requirements inside the query. If your problem is that it not always pairs, this is a valid case. Consider a line with `A-10m-B--20m--C`. In this case, the closest point to `C` will be `B`, but the closet point to `B` will be `A`. Is this what you mean by breaking? What is your expected results in such a case? Only `A-C` pair? `B-C` should be drooped?

Comment: My bad, the code is really running as expected. I'm running the same query in other databases as well and they are returning always the pair of nodes, because I run a CROSS JOIN and them I filter everything. Now I see you optimized this situation.