# K Closest Pair in SurrealDB in only one query

Tags: node.js, database, surrealdb

I have a set of points in surrealDB originated from OSM files, I want to know the K closest pair based on a tag
For example, I have the set structured like

```
[
{id: nodes:0, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}},
{id: nodes:1, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}, ${key}: ${value}},
{id: nodes:2, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}, ${key}: ${value}},
{id: nodes:3, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}},
{id: nodes:4, location: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [long, lat]}, ${key}: ${value}},
]
```

And I want to get the K Closest for each other. I've done the similar query in different databases as well, [here you have mongodb for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77076414/closest-pair-location-on-mongodb-in-only-one-query/77076664#77076664) (thanks Mr. serok for that one)

Other example of the same query using

```
// neo4j
MATCH (node1:POINT {${key}: '${value}'})
MATCH (node2:POINT {${key}: '${value}'})
WHERE node1.id <> node2.id
WITH node1, node2
ORDER BY point.distance(node1.location, node2.location)
LIMIT ${k}
RETURN node1, node2, point.distance(node1.location, node2.location) AS distance;
```

```
// mysql with cross join
WITH tagged_nodes AS (
    SELECT node_id, location
    FROM nodes
    WHERE node_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT nt1.node_id
        FROM node_tags nt1
        WHERE nt1.tag_key = ${key} AND nt1.tag_value = ${value}
    )
)
SELECT
    nt1.node_id AS node_id1,
    nt2.node_id AS node_id2,
    ST_Distance_Sphere(nt1.location, nt2.location) AS distance
FROM tagged_nodes nt1
CROSS JOIN tagged_nodes nt2
WHERE nt1.node_id != nt2.node_id
ORDER BY distance ASC
LIMIT ${k};
```

I've tried to do a query like this one bellow, but the SPLIT statement stops me from using the WHERE statement afterwards to filter equal nodes

```
SELECT id, location,
(SELECT id, location FROM nodes WHERE ${key} = ${value}) AS target
FROM (SELECT id, location FROM nodes WHERE ${key} = ${value}) 
SPLIT target
WHERE id != target.id
SORT BY geo::distance(location, target.location) ASC
LIMIT ${k};
```